# How can to set the wait time await result

Tags: c#, async-await, botframework

I have in my ms bot framework:

```
private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
{
    var activity = await result as Activity;
    context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
}
```

How can I to set the wait time `await result`?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you try something like the following:

```
private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
{
    // Set the delay to whatever timeout interval you need (in milliseconds)
    if (Task.WaitAny(result.ToTask(), Task.Delay(1000)) == result) 
    {
        var activity = await result as Activity;
    }
    else
    {
        // Didn't complete during the defined interval
    }

    context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
}
```

**Update**

Added usage of [ToTask()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.internals.fibers.extensions.totask?view=botbuilder-dotnet-3.0#Microsoft_Bot_Builder_Internals_Fibers_Extensions_ToTask__1_Microsoft_Bot_Builder_Dialogs_IAwaitable___0__) to transform the `IAwaitable` to a `Task` that can be used with `WhenAny`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thakns man, but I have error in string 'if (Task.WaitAny(result, Task.Delay(1000)) == result)'  - Argument 1: Cannot convert from "Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.IAwaitable <object>" to "System.Threading.Tasks.Task". 
I think convert would not be a good idea.

Comment: See update on how to transform the `IAwaitable` to a `Task`